# Select box not showing properly on a survey form

Tags: html, css

```css
​div{
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        Occupation: <select name="occupation">
       <option value="student1">Student (high school or less)</option>
       <option value = "student2">University student</option>
       <option value = "unemployed">Unemployed</option>
       <option value="intern">Internship</option>
       <option value="full-time">Full Time Job</option>
       <option value="retired">In Retirement</option>
     </div>
       
       <div>
        What do you like the most about our product? <select name="likes">
         <option value="look">The Look</option>
         <option value="functionality">Functionality</option>
         <option value="usefulness">Usefulness</option>
         <option value="users">Other Users</option>
         
       </div>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why is the first select box working and the other one isn't
This is what it looks like:
[image]

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You never closed the first (or second) select. You need `</select>`

Comment: Issue is due to missing closing tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close your `div` and `select` tags.

```css
​div{
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
        Occupation: <select name="occupation">
       <option value="student1">Student (high school or less)</option>
       <option value = "student2">University student</option>
       <option value = "unemployed">Unemployed</option>
       <option value="intern">Internship</option>
       <option value="full-time">Full Time Job</option>
       <option value="retired">In Retirement</option>
       </select>
     </div>
       
       <div>
        What do you like the most about our product? <select name="likes">
         <option value="look">The Look</option>
         <option value="functionality">Functionality</option>
         <option value="usefulness">Usefulness</option>
         <option value="users">Other Users</option>
         </select>
       </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic due to a typo. Don't farm rep from a question that has no value to anyone

Comment: @j08691 How is this a typo? The OP didnt close his tags _twice_, that's clearly not a typo. Furthermore, even if the OP had forgotten it that doesn't mean it's no value to the OP, your reason to downvote is very flawed.

Comment: It's a typo in that he simply omitted a closing tag. It's a mistake. Has no value to anyone other than the OP.

Comment: @j08691 Which means it has value to someone.

Comment: I wouldn't know who would consider invalid markup as "helpful". Voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing tag of your first `<select>`:

```css
​div{
  padding: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div>
     Occupation: 
    <select name="occupation">
       <option value="student1">Student (high school or less)</option>
       <option value = "student2">University student</option>
       <option value = "unemployed">Unemployed</option>
       <option value="intern">Internship</option>
       <option value="full-time">Full Time Job</option>
       <option value="retired">In Retirement</option>
      </select> <!-- was missing -->
     </div>
       
       <div>
        What do you like the most about our product? <select name="likes">
         <option value="look">The Look</option>
         <option value="functionality">Functionality</option>
         <option value="usefulness">Usefulness</option>
         <option value="users">Other Users</option>
         
       </div>
```

Comment: Vote to close as off-topic due to a typo. Don't farm rep from a question that has no value to anyone.

Comment: I dont see how it could be off topic

Comment: For the same reason one asking about invalid code that a compiler can't compile due to errors in the code. If the OP would have run it through the validator, as everyone should be doing (right?), it would be glaringly obvious what the error is and he wouldn't have to waste our time with it.